# How to run linear regression on a dataset, taking each time a single variable as the dependent variable?

Tags: r, analytics, rstudio, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset having all numeric variables called 'dt'.. want to take each single variable as dependent variable and find the best combination of the remaining predictor variables using step wise regression.. and if the resulting "best combination" gives an adjusted R^2 >0.70, output it to the console.. HEre's my naive attempt at doing it.

```
for(i in ncol(dt)){
    nul<-lm(dt[,i]~1,data=dt)
    ful<-lm(dt[,i]~.,data=dt)
    model<-step(nul,scope = list(lower=nul,upper=ful),direction="forward",trace=FALSE)
    if((summary(lm(as.formula(model$call),data=dt)))$adj.r.squared>0.70){
        print(as.formula(model$call))
        cat(paste("\n"))
    }
}
```

Here's the undesired output which I am getting:

```
dt[, i] ~ Y

Warning messages:
1: attempting model selection on an essentially perfect fit is nonsense 
2: In summary.lm(lm(as.formula(model$call), data = dt)) :
essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Comment: If you get this working it will create statistical "junk".

Comment: There are statistically "honest" methods of doing multiple comparisons. Your method on the other hand has the deprecatory name: "data dredging". If you want to leave your life of statistical crime behind and follow a righteous life, then learn to use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/generalsiminf.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As @42- has rightly pointed out, what you will get is statistical "junk".

But if you do insist of "testing" it out anyway, it is quite easy to get r^2 of multiple linear mods using leaps::regsubsets.

```
library(leaps)
a <- regsubsets(as.matrix(x=swiss[,-1]),y=swiss[,1], nvmax=1, nbest=100, intercept=F, method="exhaustive", really.big=T)
summary(a) 

Subset selection object
5 Variables 
                 Forced in Forced out
Examination          FALSE      FALSE
Education            FALSE      FALSE
Catholic             FALSE      FALSE
Infant.Mortality     FALSE      FALSE
100 subsets of each size up to 1
Selection Algorithm: exhaustive
         Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
1  ( 1 ) " "         " "         " "       " "      "*"             
1  ( 2 ) "*"         " "         " "       " "      " "             
1  ( 3 ) " "         "*"         " "       " "      " "             
1  ( 4 ) " "         " "         " "       "*"      " "             
1  ( 5 ) " "         " "         "*"       " "      " "
```

In the example above, 5 lm mods with 'Fertility' as dependent variable, and each remaining variable as single predictor for each model, e.g. Fertility ~ Infant, Fertility ~ Agriculture etc.

```
summary(a)$rsq # returns R^2 for each of the five models

[1] 0.9703145 0.8558076 0.7054873 0.5660736 0.4474043
```

By changing the above as a function, say:

```
nonsense_lm <- function(data, x) regsubsets(as.matrix(x=data[,-x]),y=data[,x], nvmax=1, nbest=100, intercept=F, method="exhaustive", really.big=T)
```

Then loop each variable as predictor:

```
nonsense <- lapply(1:ncol(swiss), function(x) nonsense_lm(swiss, x))
lapply(nonsense, function(x)summary(x)$rsq)

 [[1]]
 [1] 0.9703145 0.8558076 0.7054873 0.5660736 0.4474043

 [[2]]
 [1] 0.8558076 0.8121654 0.5785572 0.4961365 0.2715248

 [[3]]
 [1] 0.7844437 0.7729180 0.7054873 0.4961365 0.2132834

 [[4]]
 [1] 0.7729180 0.5456765 0.4474043 0.2715248 0.2137402

 [[5]]
 [1] 0.5785572 0.5660736 0.5135628 0.2137402 0.2132834

 [[6]]
 [1] 0.9703145 0.8121654 0.7844437 0.5456765 0.5135628
```

Again, please be mindful that the R^2 is effectively statistical "junk". Having a proper question to test is the most critical step for any analysis.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I didn't get why I will get statistical junk.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: 'cos storks deliver babies (p < 0.008) http://www.econ.queensu.ca/files/other/storks.pdf

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar Actually, you also run into the multiple testing problem, basically making your p-values about as accurate as a random number generator. Remember that in every 20 regressions on purely random data, on average one will be "significant". Google "type 1 error" and "familywise error rate" for more information.